# Concise yet Rigorous Proof: How to Modify It?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, article-writing

The following proposition is standard.

**Proposition  1**. Let $G$ be a graph with a planar drawing $D$ and at least three vertices. Then, $D$ can be extended to a multi planar drawing $D^*$ by adding some uncrossed edges such that $D^*$ is triangulated.

I give a brief proof (just briefly mention it), but I always feel like it lacks accuracy.

> **Proof:** It is always possible to triangulate $D$ by   repeatedly **adding** uncrossed edges to **face** with degree more than three.

I feel that the phrase **adding  uncrossed
edges to the face** is not good. I mean if a face  $f$ with degree more than three, then there are two non-consecutive vertices on the boundary of $f$, then we can add the edge between the two non-consecutive vertices and draw the edge inside the face. Then we can triangulate $D$ by repeating the above process.

But the passage above appears to be verbose. I would like to provide a concise yet rigorous proof (actually, just briefly mention it). How should I modify it?

Note that the degree of a face is the length of its boundary.

---

In fact, I'm also considering the case of a 1-planar graph (A graph is called 1-planar if it can be drawn in the plane so that each its edge is crossed by at most one other edge).

Similarly I take into account the following statement:

**Proposition  2**. Let $G$ be a graph with a 1-planar drawing $D$ and at least three vertices. Then, $D$ can be extended to a multi 1-planar drawing $D^*$ by adding some edges such that $D^*$ is triangulated.

Before I give its proof, I give this lemma.

**Lemma 1.** Let $G$ be a $1$-planar graph with a $1$-planar drawing $D$. Let $f$ be a
$k$-region of $D$ where $k\ge 4$. Then there are at least two non-consecutive
vertices on the boundary of $f$.

Similarly, I also wish to provide a concise yet rigorous proof. Now I can say:  **By Lemma 1, , it is always possible to triangulate $D$ by
repeatedly adding uncrossed edges to region with degree more than three.** Likewise, I also find it lacking in rigor.

Comment: What is a multi planar drawing? There's no need for "uncrossed" or for edge**s**. You can only ever add one edge to a face $f$. Once the edge is added $f$ stops existing because now it is subdivided into two new faces $f_1$ and $f_2$. I would write this as "by repeatedly subdividing the faces of degree more than three with a diagonal edge".

Comment: The term "multi planar drawing" here means the possibility of encountering multiple edges (though, for planar graphs, simplicity can always be maintained, and triangulation is possible).

Comment: @RandyMarsh For 1-planar graph, we may need the terms  "uncrossed edge" and "multi 1-planar drawing"

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, a multi planar drawing is a planar embedding of a multi graph? Though now I'm a bit confused. First of all, is $G$ a graph or a multi-graph? Then, the quoted proof is about $D$, which is a planar drawing of $G$. The multi-planar drawing is denoted $D^*$ (or rather, the multi-planar extension of $D$). How can we encounter multiple edges in $D$? More precisely, is it not the case that we can always avoid multiple edges in $D$ simply by not subdividing a face with a copy of an existing edge, but by always using a "proper" new edge?

Comment: You are right. First, $G$ is simple otherwise if it contains a face with degree 2, then we cannot add edge to make the face triangulated.

Comment: For a simple planar graph and its planar drawing,  we can choose “proper” edges to make the final triangulated drawing simple(i.e., contain no multi-edges). It can be proven. 
But now, I do not care the simplicity.

Comment: @licheng Your question about triangulation of 1-planar graphs is very interesting. But here's what I didn't find (maybe because I didn't search well.) How to define a region for such graphs?

Comment: It is contained in my manuscript. My intention was to learn how to write that passage concisely. A rigorous proof is already available. For information about regions of 1-planar graphs, you can refer to Biedl's article: A note of 1-planar graphs with minimum degree 7.

Comment: @kabenyuk The given 1-planar drawing Γ  defines the regions, which are the connected parts of R \ Γ .

Comment: @licheng Thanks. Biedl's article is also very interesting.